# Getting a TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am a python beginner and I do not understand the error I am getting for this code.

I am trying to find an x value equal to or as close to 100mm/0.1m as possible using the bisector method.

This is my error:

if z <= 100:

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Code:

```
xL, xR = 0, 10
m= 800
k=5E6
xM = (xL + xR)/2

def dispcalc(m,k,xM):    #Dispalcement Function
    xL, xR = 0, 10       # Initial x Left and x Right

    xM = (xL + xR) / 2     #Midpoint of xL and xR
    print(xM)

z = (dispcalc(m,k,xM))
while z != 100:
    xM = (xL + xR) /2
    if z <= 100:
        xR=xM
        xM = (xL + xR) / 2
        z = dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
       
    else:
        xL = xM
        xM = (xL + xR) / 2
        z = dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
       
    dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
    print(xM, z)
```

Or the other error is the code prints nothing,  if i use the while loop within the def dispcalc function.

```
xL, xR = 0, 10
m= 800
k=5E6
xM = (xL + xR)/2

def dispcalc(m,k,xM):    #Dispalcement Function
    xL, xR = 0, 10       # Initial x Left and x Right

    xM = (xL + xR) / 2     #Midpoint of xL and xR
    print(xM)
    z = (dispcalc(m,k,xM))
    while z != 100:
        xM = (xL + xR) /2
        if z <= 100:
            xR=xM
            xM = (xL + xR) / 2
            z = dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
        
        else:
            xL = xM
            xM = (xL + xR) / 2
            z = dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
        
        dispcalc(800, 5E6, xM)
        print(xM, z)
```

Comment: `print` and `return` mean two different things. `discalc` doesn't return the value of `xM`.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It's unclear what code is inside the *dispcalc* function. You're also confusing local and global variables with the same name (xM)

Comment: I have changed the indentation. I have tried putting everything within the dispcalc function

Comment: This code will not produce any output because dispcalc is never invoked. You need to review Python's pass by value and pass by reference strategies as well as local/global variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `dispcalc` is lacking a `return` statement. Currently, you perform some calculations and print the result, but do not keep any reference to such result in memory, which is what `return` does. Thus, `dispcalc` returns `None`. Then you assign that value ( `None`) to the variable `z` and that's why you get that error.

Correct code (in your first snippet):

```
def dispcalc(m,k,xM):    #Dispalcement Function
    xL, xR = 0, 10       # Initial x Left and x Right

    xM = (xL + xR) / 2     #Midpoint of xL and xR
    print(xM)  #this is in fact not needed
    return(xM)
```

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now the return This has helped thank you! But now I am stuck in an endless loop and not sure why this is happening.

Comment: That's because `z` is converging to zero, but I think you should write a new question for that, because the initial error is now solved. If you agree on that, please accept my answer (but no pressure). However, I suggest you review the method. AFAIK you need a tolerance value `e`, and then do `while abs(z-100)>e`. But you have additional problems, for example, you're not truly using `m` and `k ` anywhere and `dispcalc` should not assign  `xL, xR = 0, 10` because it will always get stuck.